# Override name of file field link in Drupal field.tpl template

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a file download field in a node. The field displays as a simple link with the name of the file that will be downloaded, eg:

**picture.png**

What I want to do is rename the name on the link, i.e. I want it to stay the same but say:

**Download the picture**,

instead.

I have created a field--resource.tpl template, I don't know how to get started to get the name that is displayed overridden.

Here is what is in my field--field-source--resources.tpl file:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way to approach this without having to go through the template file:

On the 'edit' page for your content type, you can set it to 'enable description field'

[image]

which will add a new field to your content form that will let you override the label for the file, ex:

[image]

This should be easier than trying to parse the template approach and will work seamlessly with other modules that interact with the file field.